# Be van with problem at higher altitudes

Tags: engine, vw, stall, euro-van

2000 euro van engine shuts off when reaching altitude of 9000 feet in mountains. After standing for 20 minutes, it starts. This happened twice but ran well when not in the mountains. Similar to cars with carburetor that get vapor lock. What could be the problem? I had new plugs, gas filter, and air filter work done. Could this be bad gas cap. It does not overheat.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed or have any more information which might help in the diagnosis?